# animate scrolling after append jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I do a simple horizontal scroll like this (fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Xwr8P/1/):

```
$('#previousBtn').click(function(){
    $('.anImage').last().clone().prependTo("#scrollContainer");
    $('.anImage').last().remove();
});

$('#nextBtn').click(function(){
    $('.anImage').first().clone().appendTo("#scrollContainer");
    $('.anImage').first().remove();
});
```

Works great... but I can't seem to figure out how to animate a scroll effect while flipping through. I have googled and can only find solutions for vertical scrolling after appending. here's My Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Xwr8P/1/ when you flip through it's very rigid obviously because its just being appended and removed. Looking for a way to animate a scroll.

Comment: Not a solution but just a tip, you can use `$('.anImage').last().insertBefore($('.anImage').first())` it's shorter and clearer, no cloning and no need to remove the previous one

Comment: I would probably go the plugin route because this has been done a thousand times, but this could work for your example -  http://jsfiddle.net/devitate/Xwr8P/4/